# .tpl использование тегов {}

Tags: tpl

Почему я не могу вывести например тег {slider} нигде кроме главной страницы? Где задаются эти правила? В интернете не нашел ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покажу вам на простейшем примере:
файл *.tpl содержит:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>{title}</title>
{css}
</head>
<body>
<div id="full">
<div id="header">
<img src="./templates/start/images/header.gif" alt="header">
</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="navigation">
{menu}
</div>
<div id="login">
<center>{login}</center>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="news">
<center>{name}</center><br />
<center>{photo}</center><br />
{description}<br />
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<img src="/templates/start/images/footer.gif" alt="footer">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

файл *.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
$tmp=file_get_contents("../../templates/start/main.tpl");
$title="Головна сторінка";
$css="<link href='../../templates/start/css/engine.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />";

//підключаємо меню з файлу
$navigation=''; // Обнуляем переменную
function callback($s) // Эта функция будет вызываться вместо вывода данных браузеру
{
        $GLOBALS['navigation'].=$s; // Новые данные добавляем к переменной
}
ob_start('callback'); // Включаем кеширование и указываем, что вместо отправки данных клиенту, их нужно отправлять в функцию callback
include 'menu.php'; // Просто выполняем скрипт
ob_end_flush();   // Выключаем кеширование... теперь все данные будут уходить браузеру
$menu="$navigation";


//підключаємо файл входу в систему
$log=''; // Обнуляем переменную
function callback1($s1) // Эта функция будет вызываться вместо вывода данных браузеру
{
        $GLOBALS['log'].=$s1; // Новые данные добавляем к переменной
}
ob_start('callback1'); // Включаем кеширование и указываем, что вместо отправки данных клиенту, их нужно отправлять в функцию callback
include 'login.php'; // Просто выполняем скрипт
ob_end_flush();   // Выключаем кеширование... теперь все данные будут уходить браузеру
$login="$log";



include ("../../configuration/config.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM main";
$result=mysql_query($query); 
$r=mysql_fetch_array($result); 
$name=$r['name'];
$photo=$r['photo'];
$description=$r['description'];




$tmp = ereg_replace("{title}", $title, $tmp);
$tmp = ereg_replace("{css}", $css, $tmp);
$tmp = ereg_replace("{menu}", $menu, $tmp);
$tmp = ereg_replace("{name}", $name, $tmp);
$tmp = ereg_replace("{photo}", $photo, $tmp);
$tmp = ereg_replace("{description}", $description, $tmp);
$tmp = ereg_replace("{login}", $login, $tmp);
echo $tmp;
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но есть еще пару вопросов:
Припустим  создан .tpl файл и .php Как теперь узнать ссылку? Которую можно забить в строку браузера и увидеть созданную страницу

Answer (score 0):

Этот тег в tpl является именем переменной, которую в конкретный шаблон из php передали. Надо slider на другой странице - передавайте эту переменную или массив в нужный шаблон и он будет доступен